# Is there a way to continuously send snippets of audio being recorded in realtime to backend server in Flutter.io?

Tags: flutter, audio-streaming, speech-to-text, flutter-plugin, mozilla-deepspeech

I am creating an application that uses Mozilla's Deep Speech API to transcribe the user's speech to text. The input requires audio files with some sort of format and in order for this app to work, I will need to continuously send these audio files to my flask server while the user is recording audio.

I have seen that most flutter plugins only allow you to record, pause, and stop, however, I need to find a way to keep on recording while also sending audio files. If anyone has found a way to accomplish this using Flutter.io's recording plugins, any guidance and information would help.

My backup plan is to use one of Flutter's Speech-To-Text plugins like this one: `https://pub.dev/packages/speech_to_text#-example-tab-`, and then to send over the text to my backend server through a websocket. However, I don't know what kind of API they're using to transcribe and how accurate the text gets transcribed to.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this? Or would anyone happen to know if another framework like Swift/React-Native can accomplish this?